# Number of integer solutions to the equation $x_1 + x_2 + x_3 + x_4 = 21$ such that $x_i \in [0, 10]$

Tags: combinatorics, combinations

I want to find the number of solutions to the following equation 
$$x_1+x_2+x_3+x_4 = 21$$ such that $x_i$ is in $[0,10]$

I know that total solutions will be ${24}\choose3$ but this will also include solutions where $x_i$ is not in $[0,10]$. So how do I find the solution to this problem?

Comment: The quantity $\binom{20}{3}$ is actually the number of solutions in the positive integers, not the nonnegative integers.

Comment: Yeah right, I’ve made the correction, thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As you observed, the number of solutions of the equation 
$$x_1 + x_2 + x_3 + x_4 = 21 \tag{1}$$
in the nonnegative integers is 
$$\binom{21 + 4 - 1}{4 - 1} = \binom{24}{3}$$
From these, we must subtract those solutions in which one or more of the variables exceeds $10$.  There can be at most one such variable since $2 \cdot 11 = 22 > 21$.

We count the number of solutions that violate the restriction that $x_i \leq 10$, $1 \leq i \leq 4$.

Choose which of the four variables exceeds $10$.  Suppose it is $x_1$.  Then $x_1' = x_1 - 11$ is a nonnegative integer.  Substituting $x_1' + 11$ for $x_1$ in equation 1 yields
\begin{align*}
x_1' + 11 + x_2 + x_3 + x_4 & = 21\\
x_1' + x_2 + x_3 + x_4 & = 10 \tag{2}
\end{align*}
Equation 2 is an equation in the nonnegative integers with
$$\binom{10 + 4 - 1}{4 - 1} = \binom{13}{3}$$
solutions.  Hence, there are 
$$\binom{4}{1}\binom{13}{3}$$
solutions in the nonnegative integers that violate the restriction that $x_i \leq 10$, $1 \leq i \leq 4$.

Hence, the number of admissible solutions is 
$$\binom{24}{3} - \binom{4}{1}\binom{13}{3}$$

Answer (score 3):

I would find coefficient of  $x^{21}$  in the expansion of $$(1+x+x^2+x^3+...+x^{10})^4$$ 
Calculate $1+x+x^2+x^3+...+x^{10}$ by G.P. and then using formulas for finding coefficients for binomial and negative binomial you can find the coefficient.

Comment: This [tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) explains how to typeset mathematics on this site.

Comment: @N.F.Taussig thank you ...i first tried typing but I typied $x^21$  so I got confused